# Update table with values VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to figure how to update a table if a value already exists when I try to insert it.

Ex, I use the following code to check if the name is already registered.
But if it does exists on the table, how can I make an update on the already existent ID, to update for the new name?
Thanks

```
Try
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server =" + server + ";" + "user id=" + username + ";" _
                                                + "password =" + password + ";" + "database=" + database
    sqlConn.Open()
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teste1    " &
    " WHERE ID =     '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    If sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar <> 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("ID already exists.")
        'user is valid
    Else

        objconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=clientes"
        objconn.Open()
        Dim objcmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("UPDATE teste1 WHERE (Name,ID)VALUES(@field1,@field2)", objconn)
        With objcmd
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", Name)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", ID)

            MsgBox("Done!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Great!")
        End With
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objcmd.Dispose()
        objconn.Close()
        'user is not valid
    End If
    sqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Ops!")
Finally

End Try
```

Comment: I don't think your update syntax is correct.  shouldn't it be `Update Test set Name = @field1 where ID = @Field2`

Comment: also maybe you are looking for a merge or upsert statement.  this will insert if the condition does not exist and update if it does exist. search for merge for your rdbms.

Comment: It's very annoying when people copy code from VS from the first character in the first line and then include the leading whitespace in all the other lines. Look at your code. Do you think that's easy to read? Consideration is literally considering how what you do affects others. Forcing us to scroll right to read your code is inconsiderate. Simply hold down the Alt key when selecting in VS and you can remove the leading whitespace from the whole block. Even without that, you could still remove the whitespace after pasting.

Comment: I'm new to this, I'm really sorry for my mistakes about the code display
I solved my problem thanks to Bryan Dellinger

Answer (score 0):

You could use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Then it would be one statement.